# Question for NSolve

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

When I am writing the following code

```
NSolve[x Cosh[x]==0,x]
```

I received as an answer

```
{{x->0.},{x->0.-1.5708i},{x->0.+1.5708i}}
```

But when using this

```
NSolve[x Cosh[x]-1==0,x]
```

or in general

```
NSolve[x Cosh[x]-a==0,x]
```

I have this answer "This system cannot be solved with the methods available to NSolve."

Could someone explain me why?

Comment: If you restrict the domain to real numbers, it can solve it. `NSolve[x Cosh[x] - 1 == 0, x, Reals]` gives `{{x -> 0.76501}}`

Comment: @Nasser Does the same apply to the parameters?

Comment: **Does the same apply to the parameters?** since `NSolve` is numerical basesd, it can't really solve an equation with unknown parameters in it (same for finding Roots). For this you need to try symbolic solver such as `Solve` or `Reduce`.

Comment: @Nasser Those do not work for the parameters too. Thank you for your help. Thought!

Comment: I do not under what **Those do not work too** mean. what does not work on what?

Comment: @Nasser ``` Solve``` and ```Reduce```  do not work for the parameters. I receive the same answer ``` This system cannot be solved with the methods available to Solve```

Comment: oh, yes. I did not mean that Solve or Reduce will neccessarly be able to solve the equation. I just meant if you have parameters with unknown values, then these what you should use. Not all non-linear equations have analytical solutions ofcourse. In this case, you can try NSolve but set specific value(s) for your `a`.